# Express angular app not serving assets in ie9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have an angular/express application. It works fine in all browsers but when testing IE9 I am getting 304/Aborted on all of my assets.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/vendor/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/raw/alertWrapper.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/raw/df-alerts.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/raw/df-app-loader.css" />
```

please note that the root is actually "/app" so app/index, app/css, etc....

i am using `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));`

I am seeing this in IE:

[image: ie9 assets not loading]

Notice the http:///css.....

Comment: How does the html where the css are linked look like?

Answer (score 0):

The status code 304 actually means "not modified". This happens when the browser sends a request for a file and indicates that it has a cached version (using conditional headers like [If-Modified-Since](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since) or [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) based ones).

If the cache contents of the browser are up to date, the server responds with a status code of 304 and some headers only and the browser is expected to abort the connection and serve the local content.

So without further information, your app most likely works as expected and the problems you're having with IE have a different cause.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently IE9 has limits the amount of stylesheets you can load.  I was loading about 50 or more. I reduced to 4 and the problem went away.